# Data must be a single matrix Y or a list of pairs X,Y

Tags: matlab, plot, ode

I want to make two line plots Ckkk and Ckk appear on the same plot. The above error keeps occurring. I've checked with similar problem and none of the fixes have helped.

The code is as below

```
 function cancer()
 clear all;
 clc;
 t0=0;tend=60;nt=tend;
 dt=(tend-t0)/(nt-1);
 t=t0:dt:tend;
 mambda=0.75;nambda=0.50;lambda=0.25;phi=0.0;psi=0.0;

 %nu cell kill strength
 %nu=zeros(length(t));
 %inu= find(t>=40);
 %nu(inu)=0.12;

 %mu cell kill strength
 %mu=zeros(length(t));
 %inu = t>=40;
 %mu(inu)=0.22;

 %lu cell kill strength
 %lu=zeros(length(t));
 %inu= t>=40;
 %lu(inu)=0.32;



C(1)=100;Ca=100;Cb=100;Ct=100;
Ctt=100;Cttt=100;Cx=100;Ckk=100;Ck=100;Ckkk=100;K(1)=300; 

for i=1:length(t)-1
    %Equation ?c
    Cx(i+1)=Cx(i)+dt*(lambda*Cx(i));

    %Equation ?c(1-c/K)with different  ? values.
    Ck(i+1)=Ck(i)+dt*(lambda*Ck(i)*(1-(Ck(i)/K(i))));
    Ckk(i+1)=Ckk(i)+dt*(nambda*Ckk(i)*(1-(Ckk(i)/K(i))));
    Ckkk(i+1)=Ckkk(i)+dt*(mambda*Ckkk(i)*(1-(Ckkk(i)/K(i))));

    %Gompertz Growth Equations with different  ? values.
    C(i+1)=C(i)+dt*(-lambda*C(i)*log(C(i)/K(i)));


    %Anti-tumor treatment induces a tumor cell kill with strength 0?nu?1.
    %Ct(i+1)=Ct(i)+dt*(-lambda*Ct(i)*log(Ct(i)./K(i)))-nu(i).*Ct(i);


    %Anti-angiogenic treatment 
    K(i+1)=K(i)+dt*(phi*C(i)-psi*K(i).*((C(i)).^(2/3)));
```

When I call the plot function, Error on plot occurs

```
plot(Ckkk,'b',Ckk,'r');
xlabel('Time In Days')
ylabel('Number of Cells')
end
```

Comment: what is `size(Ckkk)` and `size(Ckk)`?

Comment: the initial value of Ckkk and Ckk is 100. Or that isn't what you are asking for?

Comment: Nop. I am asking what is `siza(Ckkk)` . Literally. Copy paste this in MATLAB and run it

Comment: I tried size(Ckk) and it gave the error 'Undefined function or variable 'Ckk' '

Answer (score 2):

Just like the error says, you need to specify the `X` coordinates if more than a single matrix of `Y` coordinates is provided. In your case, you have two, `Ckkk` and `Ckk`. If you need to plot those as two independent variables, one solution is below

```
figure; clf;
plot(t, Ckkk,'b', t,Ckk,'r');
```

Another solution is

```
figure; clf;
hold on;
plot(t, Ckkk,'b');
plot(t, Ckk,'r');
hold off;
```

In the later, you can actually skip `t`, because you are providing a single `Y` matrix to each `plot` function.

It is generally a good idea to check the [documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) before you post a question here.

Comment: thank you but even after this fix the program still gives an error. Let me try to fix it.